# how to convert data types of variables in java

Tags: java

I have a problem that I want to display double type data in integer type when there is no any . (dot) in data or there is . (dot) in data then display float type data. In java

```
i.e.

double a=2;
double b=4;
double sum=a+b;
sum=6.0

but i want sum=6

OR
double a=2.1;
double b=4;
double sum=a+b;
sum=6.1

but i want sum=6
```

Comment: If the sum is 6.6 what U need to print ???

Comment: sorry in lat row sum=6.1

Answer (score 2):

You can use the cast syntax. Note that this would raise a warning in most compilers/IDEs, as you are losing precision here:

```
int sum = (int)(a + b);
```

Comment: You would get a compile-time error and not a warning as loss of precision occurs

Comment: Loss of precision will result in a compiler error **unless** you have an explicit cast (like I demonstrated in the answer). However, most IDEs still treat this as a warning.

Answer (score 1):

use a cast...

(int)double or else you can declare an int variable and assign that to double.You need to add cast as there is loss of precision

int value =(int)double_val

Answer (score 0):

you have to cast your variable to an integer:
try it out like this:

```
System.out.println((int)(66.314));
System.out.println((int)(sum));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sum variable should be casted into an integer...
Try this:

```
double a=2.1;
double b=4;
double sum=a+b;
int sumInt=(int)sum;
```

Answer (score 0):

use casting in Java to print out your result. 
For more information , please see

```
http://howtoprogramwithjava.com/java-cast/
```